# My site using "defer" for fast loading, but ruining the site for Opera Mini, any workaround?

Tags: javascript, css, browser, cross-browser, opera-mini

My site using "defer" for all of its scripts for fast loading, and Opera Mini doesn't support defer loading, any way to workaround this? I still want to use defer but also to work fine on Opera Mini as 15% of my visitors are using them.

And also, why is Opera Mini breaking some of my CSS? I think it's weird browser, I know they want it fast, but at least do it with same compatibility and rendering as other browsers.

*Edit: Additional info, I also use caching plugin (W3TC), so this might be more trickier.

Comment: What CSS it breaks? Support for some features like shadows, border-radius etc. is deliberately disabled for using less data and faster rendering, however most layout should be preserved.

Comment: Yeah, like shadows, border-radius, can't use icon beside SVG, even with SVG it will break, out of place and different size. Even it has its own standarized font size. A lot of thing to do to make it good looking on Opera Mini. Not to mention if you use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

> Opera Mini doesn't support defer loading, any way to workaround this

`defer` just move script execution at the end of parsing HTML and this doesn't make sence if all scripts have `defer`. Opera Mini will just omit it and download all content, make it as OBML and push to the phone. If you have any problems with Javascript in Opeara Mini, I think this is not defer problem. Take a look at the `server:console` in Opera Mini and check it for javascript errors.

> why is Opera Mini breaking some of my CSS

Opera Mini doesn't support CSS3.

Comment: Soon after I posted the question I found out that Opera Mini behave really different compared to other browsers. Limited CSS and JS. Since it's impossible to create a site with same UX as other browsers on Opera Mini, now I choose to make it as simple as possible on OM. People using OM because they want it light and simple. Thanks!